# Azure CLI script variables giving errors

Tags: azure, azure-cli

I'm trying to run the sample script found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-quickstart-containers-linux#create-a-service-fabric-cluster

```
#!/bin/bash

# Variables
ResourceGroupName='containertestcluster' 
ClusterName='containertestcluster' 
Location='eastus' 
Password='q6D7nN%6ck@6' 
Subject='containertestcluster.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com' 
VaultName='containertestvault' 
VmPassword='Mypa$$word!321'
VmUserName='sfadminuser'

# Login to Azure and set the subscription
az login

az account set --subscription <mySubscriptionID>

# Create resource group
az group create --name $ResourceGroupName --location $Location 

# Create secure five node Linux cluster. Creates a key vault in a resource group
# and creates a certficate in the key vault. The certificate's subject name must match 
# the domain that you use to access the Service Fabric cluster.  The certificate is downloaded locally.
az sf cluster create --resource-group $ResourceGroupName --location $Location --certificate-output-folder . --certificate-password $Password --certificate-subject-name $Subject --cluster-name $ClusterName --cluster-size 5 --os UbuntuServer1604 --vault-name $VaultName --vault-resource-group $ResourceGroupName --vm-password $VmPassword --vm-user-name $VmUserName
```

From the command prompt or PowerShell, I run "az login" and login, then I copy & paste this script into the console but get errors when it comes to the variables.

Comment: You need to provide more details about the error you get.

Comment: it runs each line line by line and gives error on ResourceGroupName and each variable: The term 'ResourceGroupName=containertestcluster' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

Comment: Which OS do you run the script? Windows?

Comment: Yes, Windows 10 in the Command Prompt or Powershell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you use the Shell script, it's more appropriate to run in Linux. For Windows, the PowerShell script is more suitable. And in Windows, the variables need to be set like this:

```
$varName = 'xxxx'
```

So you need to change all the variables like above. And I suggest you change the script into a PowerShell script.

Comment: Thanks, prefixing variables with $ fixed it.